# AnnotationException expected Value, got 'producto'

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I have this annotation on my controller:

```
/**
 * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 * @Route("/producto/{solicitud}/{producto}/eliminar", requirements={"solicitud": "^([0-9])+$"}, "producto": "^([0-9])+$"},
 * name="eliminarProductoSolicitud")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function eliminarProductoSolicitudAction($solicitud, $producto)
{
}
```

But any time I try to load the page I get this error:

> AnnotationException in AnnotationException.php line 42: [Syntax Error]
>   Expected Value, got 'producto' at position 141 in method
>   AppBundle\Controller\Comunes\ProductoSolicitudController::eliminarProductoSolicitudAction().

Why? What's wrong? I can't see where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `"producto": "^([0-9])+$"` inside the `requirements` curly brackets i.e.

```
 * @Route("/producto/{solicitud}/{producto}/eliminar", requirements={"solicitud": "^([0-9])+$", "producto": "^([0-9])+$"},
 * name="eliminarProductoSolicitud")
```